# How to simplify compound assignments in yosys

Tags: verilog, yosys

I am trying to get yosys to synthesize my design to structural verilog for a tool which doesn't understand the syntax  `{A, B}` to specify the concatenation of values `A` and `B`.

So for example when yosys generates statements like

```
assign C = {A,B};
assign {D,E} = F;
```

the tool chokes.  I thought of using the `splitnets` pass to eliminate multibit wires, but the multibit ports still cause yosys to generate the `{}`  syntax.  Even running `splitnets -ports` leaves some assignments like

```
assign {A, B} = {C, D}
```

I was finally able to get these assignments to disappear using an additional run of `opt`. But this seems to be a very messy way of eliminating the `{}` construct.

Is there some nicer way to eliminate this construct without splitting all the input ports?

Comment: Can you include the code for a complete verilog module that demonstrates the problem? Also: `{..}` on the right hand side of an assignment really is a problem as well?

Comment: https://github.com/jeremysalwen/combinatorial_aes  read_verilog aes_128.v table.v round.v; flatten; delete aes_128 %n; synth; write_verilog -noattr -noexpr out.v;  Now that I think about it, the {} might only be a problem on the left hand side of assignments.  Not sure though, because both types always appear together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no universally applicable way to do that. The `{..}` operator is part of verilog and thus the verilog back-end uses it when appropriate.

However, in the example you gave all cells in the verilog output have single-bit in- and outputs, so the `{..}` operator is not needed for assigning cell ports, only for assigning wires to each other.

I've used the following script (executed in your [rtl/ directory](https://github.com/jeremysalwen/combinatorial_aes/tree/master/rtl)) as a baseline:

```
read_verilog aes_128.v table.v round.v
hierarchy -top aes_128
proc; flatten; synth
# opt_clean -purge
write_verilog -noattr -noexpr out.v
```

This will produce a Verilog file with the following assignments in it that use the `{..}` operator:

```
$ grep '{' out.v
assign \a1.S4_0.in  = { key[23:0], key[31:24] };
assign { \a1.k0a [31:25], \a1.k0a [23:0] } = { key[127:121], key[119:96] };
assign \a1.v0  = { key[127:121], \a1.k0a [24], key[119:96] };
```

However, the signals `a1.S4_0.in`, `a1.k0a`, and `a1.v0` are only present in the design because yosys tries to preserve as many of the original signal names as possible, to make it easier to debug the design.

Un-commenting the `opt_clean -purge` command will let yosys remove those signals, yielding an output file that does not use the `{..}` operator:

```
$ grep -c '{' out.v 
0
```